# In the United States, what constitutes illegal "doxing"?

Tags: privacy

"Doxing" is a neologism, describing the act of publishing identifying information (or 'docs'), typically personal identifying information, on the internet. It's usually done with the intent to bring indirect harm against one individual, and is typically associated with "hacktivism" or vigilantism, but is sometimes an isolated individual act (retaliation against an unfaithful spouse, for example).

Doxing is illegal, per state and common law, but not federally, as far as I know. It also typically violates Terms of Service agreements for many types of internet services.

However, I'm interested to know what would constitute "doxing" as it's defined in case law or state laws, generally. What information would be legal or illegal to publish publicly?

Some information is publicly available. Full names, names of spouses or other family members' addresses and home phone numbers are published in phone books and on voter registration databases I can't understand how it would be illegal to essentially "re-publish" that information, but obviously information not publicly available like social security numbers or cell phone numbers.

What constitutes "doxing", as defined in the law?

Comment: Being a neologism, "doxing" is unlikely to be defined in any law.  If "doxing" is illegal, it would be because "doxing" describes behaviors that constitute other crimes that have been defined, perhaps including harassment.

Comment: Doxing itself is just the process of obtaining information regarding someone's identity from (typically) public sources. It's a form of OSINT, a common reconnaissance technique. The law may get involved depending on how you _use_ that information. Posting it in public with the intention that it leads to harassment of the individual would be illegal. Using the knowledge to "swat" the victim would also be illegal. Simply gathering the information is not, assuming the source came from online searches and not, say, hacking the victim.